# Laravel - Laravel Spatie - Resource Particular Permission [Alternative - Solution]

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

Im working on an app that lets you create groups (lets keep it simple). Im using Laravel 6 and I already have authentication and authorization.

Now, I want to assign roles of Administration or Member to a user, only to specific groups. Example:

- User A is an Admin for group A. (Can assign other user as Admin)
- User A is only a member in group B. (Can only see group information)
- User A is an Admin for group C. (Can assign other user as Admin)

Ive already tried Spatie, but it is working as general porpouses only.
Is there a way I can tweak this, any idea, article. I was also reading about Spatie - Policies

Any help provided is well received.

Comment: It looks like that the laravel-permission package by Spatie doesn't allow you to easily add permissions tied to specific model instances. You could try the [Bouncer](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer) package instead which allows you to do something like `Bouncer::allow($user)->to('edit', $post);` so restrict access to a certain model instance.

Comment: Thanks Delena. I’ll try that package and I’ll post a possible answer and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@delena-malan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3486675/delena-malan) for the comment and solution. It was possible for me to achieve this goal.

Ok, what I did was:

1. Install package of course and set it up
2. You are able to configure roles and permissions in controller or by seeder (As you want - No conflicts for me at all)
3. Get instance of Model #1 and #2 (My case User and Group)
4. Define abilities for User in Group
5. Check if User has one ability on defined Group
6. Ready to go

Ex:.

```
Bouncer::allow($user)->to('assign-admin', $group);
$boolean = $user->can('assign-admin', $group);
```